# Инициализация н-го количества карт на странице выдает ошибку ymaps.Map is not a constructor

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

При попытке инициализировать карты на странице возникает ошибка

Uncaught TypeError: ymaps.Map is not a constructor at HTMLDivElement.init

Собственно сам код

```
   var myMap;
            $(function(){
                $('.map_canvas').each(init);
            });

function init () {
    var lat = $('#myMap').attr('lat');
    var lng = $('#myMap').attr('lng');
    var z = parseInt($('#myMap').attr('z'));
    // Создаем карту с добавленными на нее кнопками.
    myMap = new ymaps.Map('myMap', {
        center: [lat,lng],
        zoom: z,
        // controls: ['routePanelControl']
    }, {
        buttonMaxWidth: 300
    });
    map = new y.Map(document.getElementById($(this).attr('initAtr')), myMap);

    Placemark();

    function Placemark() {
    var officialmarker = '/local/templates/mosokna/images/map_pin_official.png';
    var dealermarker = '/local/templates/mosokna/images/map_pin_dealer.png';
    var official_shadow ='/local/templates/mosokna/images/map_pin_official_shadow.png';
    var dealer_shadow = '/local/templates/mosokna/images/map_pin_dealer_shadow.png';    

    var lat = $(this).attr('lat');
    var lng = $(this).attr('lng');
    var z = parseInt($(this).attr('z'));
    var name='infowindow_' + $(this).attr('id');
    var info=$(this).html();
    var myshadow;
    var sizeA;
    var sizeB;

    if(!info){info = "&nbsp;"}
    var contentString = '<div class="contact_info" id="'+name+'" style="height: 250px; width: 350px;">'+info+'</div>';
    var markimage;
    if($(this).attr('official') == '1'){
            markimage = officialmarker;
            myshadow = official_shadow;
            sizeA =46;
            sizeB =50;
        } else {
            markimage = dealermarker;
            myshadow = dealer_shadow;
            sizeA =34;
            sizeB =35;
        }
    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([lat, lng], {
            // balloonContentHeader: $(this).find('h3 a').html(),
            // balloonContentBody: contentString,
            // hintContent: $(this).find('h3 a').html()
        }, 
        {
            // Опции.
            iconImageSize: [sizeA, sizeB],
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            iconImageHref: markimage,
        });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

}
// myMap.setBounds(objectManager.clusters.getBounds());
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
};
```

Comment: Код неполный, непонятно где ошибка. Подозреваю, что проблема в том что апи ещё не загружено когда вы вызываете $('.map_canvas').each(init); Начинать выполнять код связанный с JS API Карт нужно в ymaps.ready либо добавить коллбэк в параметр onload  при загрузке. https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/

Comment: Если мои советы никак не помогут, то соберите пример на jsfiddle с проблемой.

Comment: @se0ga http://jsfiddle.net/nor8jums/ - что-то вроде этого, заранее извиняюсь за качество кода.

Comment: Как я и говорил проблема в том что код апи ещё не готов когда вы выполняете new ymaps.Map так что нужно добавить ymaps.ready так ymaps.ready(function(){
       $('.map_canvas').each(init);
   })

Comment: @se0ga не поможете с инициализацией н-го количества карт на странице?

Comment: @se0ga все так как вы и говорили, ошибка пропала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что код апи ещё не готов когда вы выполняете new ymaps.Map так что нужно добавить ymaps.ready так:

```
ymaps.ready(function(){
    $('.map_canvas').each(init);
})
```